# Struggling with Inventory system on C++ Game

Tags: c++

So I am having problems when adding a quantity to an item. For example, the item Fist has a quantity of 1 and id 1. In the void addQuantity(int id, int quantity) function, i "did it" so when you type addQuantity(1, 1) for example, the item fist (which has rarity 1) will get quantity 2 but it just doesn't do anything. Can you guys help me fix it? I just need a working addQuantity, setQuantity and removeQuantity function.

Code: https://hastebin.com/itacijacur.cpp

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you produce a minimal reproducible example that exhibits the same issue and give that to us? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the index of the vector as index 1, you are wanting to scan the vector and try and find the item that has the correct id, if found then you want to make the change to the item.
Change your addQuantity function to

```
void Inventory::addQuantity(int id, int quantity) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inventoryVec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (inventoryVec.at(i).getID() == id)
        {
            inventoryVec.at(i).quantity += quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

This will cycle through the vector and find the correct item, you were assuming the items index was equal to its ID.
Hope this helps, any questions just ask.

Comment: And i actually got a question. Everything works well, but how can I remove an element from the inventory vector? I want to make it so if the quantity of the item = 0, it will get removed from the vector. I only need the code for deleting but i never knew how to do it. Would you mind helping please? Thanks again!

Comment: @Wenor Sure thing, you will do the same loop process but this time check if the quantity is 0 instead of verifying the ID like last question. When it is 0 then run inventoryVec.erase( inventoryVect.begin() + i )  You can check out the erase function here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: WORKING! Thank you so much for your help. :D

Comment: Last problem (i hope). When I want to add an item which doesn't exist to my inventory, I type the code:                                                 
`inventory.addItem("Fist", "Common",
"Never underestimate the power of your fist!",
1, 20);` in the main.cpp but it doesn't add my item to the vector.

Comment: Neverming! It was actually working but i just put it in the wrong place. Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 3):

The code that `addQuantity` executes is:

```
this->inventoryVec[id].quantity += quantity;
```

Here, you are using `id` as the **index** within `inventoryVec`. That's not the same as the id of the Item. In the scenario you have set up in your code, the index of the "fist" Item is actually 0, since it is the one and only Item added to the vector.

If you really want the `addQuantity` method to access items by their ID numbers, it would need to loop through the `inventoryVec` vector to search for an item whose ID number matches the `id` parameter of the method.